# MySQL: Fetching circular records in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, database

I've a table `ALL_DEGREES` having single column `DEGREE` which is indexed.

```
DEGREE
33
67
101
110
174
182
189
213
257
258
299
```

As we know the column can have max value 360. Now if I know a particular degree say 257, I like to fetch rows that include 257 and next 7 degrees i.e. 257, 258, 299, 33, 67, 101, 110

Is there any way to write `SELECT` query to do this?

Comment: Perhaps just select the whole table to a structure in memory and work with it in the application.

Comment: so basically the "closest" 7 degrees? `order by abs(257 - degree) limit 8`?

Comment: @MikeBrant: Nope unfortunately its huge table having DEGREE as float and lots of records.

Comment: @MarcB No. It's like: get the succeeding 7 values starting from 257. If the row count is less than 7 fill the remaining from the lowest.

Comment: ah. ok. as if you're going around in a circle...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT DEGREE
FROM ALL_DEGREES
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DEGREE >= 257 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         DEGREE
LIMIT 8
```

This achieves some sort of *circular ordering* of your records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea4d0/5)

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you

```
SELECT * FROM all_degrees
where degree >= 257
union
SELECT * FROM all_degrees
LIMIT 8;
```

Comment: Just modified to match your table/field names

Comment: Should these queries be ordered, so you're positive you're getting the closest to 257?

Comment: I would add ORDER BY clauses to both subselects, or you will not get defined order.

Comment: @MikeBrant : MySQL doesn't allow that easily - Would need to encapsulate both in another select - _"select * from (SELECT * FROM degrees
where degrees >= 257
order by degrees) x
union
select * FROM (SELECT * FROM degrees
order by degrees) y
LIMIT 8;"_

Comment: @PaulF Sure it does: `(SELECT * FROM all_degrees WHERE degree >= ? ORDER BY degree ASC LIMIT 8) UNION (SELECT * FROM all_degrees ORDER BY degree ASC) LIMIT 8;`

Comment: @MikeBrant: :-) I didn't think of simply using parentheses - without it causes an error.

Comment: @Atul : Mine's not brilliant but Giorgios's solution is